# Números aleatórios no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Esse código está gerando números aleatórios em 6 `TextViews` diferentes, mas não consigo fazer um código pra que evite que esses números se repitam.

```
package com.example.kelvin.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button btnsim;
    public TextView texto1;
    public TextView texto2;
    public TextView Texto3;
    public TextView Texto4;
    public TextView Texto5;
    public TextView Texto6;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void exibir(View view){

                Random myRandom = new Random();
                Random myRandom2 = new Random();
                Random myRandom3 = new Random();
                Random myRandom4 = new Random();
                Random myRandom5 = new Random();
                Random myRandom6 = new Random();

                int number = myRandom.nextInt(60) + 1;
                int number2 = myRandom2.nextInt(60) + 1;
                int number3 = myRandom3.nextInt(60) + 1;
                int number4 = myRandom4.nextInt(60) + 1;
                int number5 = myRandom5.nextInt(60) + 1;
                int number6 = myRandom6.nextInt(60) + 1;

                TextView mytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto1);
                TextView mytext2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto2);
                TextView mytext3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto3);
                TextView mytext4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto4);
                TextView mytext5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto5);
                TextView mytext6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto6);

                String myString = String.valueOf(number);
                String myString2 = String.valueOf(number2);
                String myString3 = String.valueOf(number3);
                String myString4 = String.valueOf(number4);
                String myString5 = String.valueOf(number5);
                String myString6 = String.valueOf(number6);

                mytext.setText(myString);
                mytext2.setText(myString2);
                mytext3.setText(myString3);
                mytext4.setText(myString4);
                mytext5.setText(myString5);
                mytext6.setText(myString6);
        }

    public void naoexibir (View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias formas de fazer. Você pode tentar usar um HashSet, que é uma coleção de objetos sem repetição.

Antes de atribuir os valores nas textviews, guarde no HashSet, pois o método add do HashSet adiciona um item apenas se ele não existir, então você pode criar um loop que adiciona infinitamente um número aleatório no HashSet enquanto o tamanho total não chegar a 6.

Por exemplo:

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet ();

do {
   Integer i = myRandom.nextInt(60) + 1;
   hs.add(i);
} while (hs.size() < 6);
```

Depois você pega o valor de cada item do HashSet (usando um Iterator) e atribui a uma TextView:

```
Iterator iterator = hs.iterator(); 

mytext.setText("" + iterator.next());
mytext2.setText("" + iterator.next());
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma olhada neste [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates).

Vou traduzir aqui pra ficar fácil:

```
public static int getRandomInt(int min, int max) {
    Random random = new Random();

    return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getRandomNonRepeatingIntegers(int size, int min,
        int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (numbers.size() < size) {
        int random = getRandomInt(min, max);

        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

E para receber 7 números aleatórios entre 0 e 25:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = getRandomNonRepeatingIntegers(7, 0, 25);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("" + list.get(i));
    }
```

**Esse método funciona bem para gerar números sem repetição com um intervalo grande (por exemplo entre 0 e 1000).**

Para casos de intervalo curto (entre 0 e 60) você pode criar uma lista contendo os números (0,1,2,3,4...60) e ir retirando os números dessa lista aleatóriamente para garantir que os próximos números não sejam repetidos. Como tirar cartas de um baralho!

Espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas formas de fazer isso, e uma opção é usar o método [`shuffle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List%3C?%3E,%20java.util.Random)) do [Collections](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html). Veja os passos:

1. Primeiro você cria um vetor de inteiros com tamanho 60.
2. Preenche todo vetor com posições de 0 a 59.
3. Use o método [Collections.shuffle](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List%3C?%3E,%20java.util.Random)) para embaralhar os valores;
4. Peque as 6 primeiras posições. ## ou se preferir, até mais.

Veja o método abaixo:

```
public static Integer[] numRandom(int qndNumbers){
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[60];
    Integer[] arrSelected = new Integer[6];;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;          
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

    for (int j = 0; j < qndNumbers; j++) {
        arrSelected[j] = arr[j]+1;
    }
    return arrSelected;
}
```

Como usar:

```
Integer[] valores  = numRandom(6);
```

Desta forma, para cada `TextView` você insere um valor em sua determinada posição. Exemplo:

```
mytext1.setText(valores[0]);
mytext2.setText(valores[2]);
mytext3.setText(valores[2]);
mytext4.setText(valores[3]);
mytext5.setText(valores[4]);
mytext6.setText(valores[5]);
```